# How to restrict plot values for scipy.stats.norm.pdf

Tags: python

I am trying to plot a gaussian PDF using scipy.stats.norm but I only want to plot y-values that fall between certain parameters (btwn 0 and 20,000). I don't want to change the shape of the PDF, just restrict the values of the plot.

I have tried several variants of the below code, but keep getting (understandable) errors:

```
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous use a.any() or a.all()
```

which make sense, but I am not sure how to get the results I want. If I try to index the y as y(i), then there is a dimension mismatch for plotting, similarly with a.any().

Any pythonic solutions welcomed -- I'm still pretty new so maybe I'm overlooking something obvious.

```
x = np.linspace(0,20000,1000)
y = norm.pdf(x, loc=3600, scale=2160)
if y in range(0,10000):
    y = z
plt.plot(x,z)
plt.savefig('continPDF')
```

Comment: Note that "truncated Gaussian" has a different meaning than a plot of a Gaussian between some values, so you may want to omit that term from your question: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Truncated_normal_distribution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to plot the pdf with those parameters, from min input value of `0` to max input value of `10000`, then you can simply do:

```
y = norm.pdf(range(0,10001), loc=3600, scale=2160)
plt.plot(y)
```

[image]

Edit: following comment from @inon-peled, see below demonstration of `scipy.stats.truncnorm`, based on the examples found in the documentation:

https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.truncnorm.html.

I have abstracted from your scale parameter for simplicity.

```
from scipy.stats import truncnorm

loc = 3600
a, b = -1000, 1000

x = np.linspace(truncnorm.ppf(0, a, b, loc=loc),
                truncnorm.ppf(1, a, b, loc=loc), 10000)

for i in [a,b,0]:
    plt.axvline(loc+i, color='black', linestyle='--', alpha=0.5, lw=1)

annotations = ['loc+a','loc+b','loc']    

for i,j in zip(annotations,[a,b,0]):
    plt.annotate(I, (loc+j,0.0001830), fontsize=8, ha='center')   

plt.plot(x, truncnorm.pdf(x, a, b, loc=loc, scale=scale), 'r')
```

[image]